# Парсинг Poizon через приложение под android

Tags: android, парсер

требуется спарсить товары по поисковому запросу из приложения Poizon на андроид. Например запрос "Nike" и получить все товары, которые будут выдаваться по этому запросу. Требуется получить по каждому товару название, цену, фото.
Сам пробовал делать, но столкнулся с тем что самого запроса со всеми товарами из выдачи найти не могу. Ставил эмулятор и через Burp Proxy анализировал запросы. Могут ли какие-то запросы не проходить через http прокси Burp?

Comment: оффтоп: попробуй Fiddler. в нем 100% все видно. главное - правильно настроить.

Comment: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html)?